# Penalizing only some parameters in maximum penalized estimation?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, regularization

Suppose that the parameters of a model ${\theta} = (\beta,\eta)\in {\mathbb R}^{p+q}$, where 
$\beta\in{\mathbb R}^p$ and $\eta\in{\mathbb R}^q$. So, the log-likelihood function can be written as

$$\ell(\theta) =  \ell(\beta,\eta).$$ 
The MLE is the value that maximizes $\ell(\beta,\eta)$.

Can I formally define a maximum penalized likelihood estimator by only penalizing $\beta$? This is, the value that maximizes

$$ \ell_p(\beta,\eta) = \ell(\beta,\eta) - p(\beta),$$
for some penalty function $p(\beta)$. If so, is there any relevant reference you can point out please?

Comment: If I may ask; what kind of problem gave rise to this question?

Comment: @Stijn It is a regression model and I only want to penalize the regression coefficients, but I want to make sure that this is a formal method.